# querying unique latest post by topic

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a recently active topics section, but i'm running into a query problem.

I have three tables: posts, topics, categories (smallest to greatest).
Every post is associated to a topic, every topic is associated to a category.

Now, the problem is displaying the most recent topic posted uniquely.

Here's a quick scenario:
User X posts in topic A, and then in topic B. User Y creates topic C and posts in topic A. Just before User Y posted on A, User Z posted on topic A.

On the active topics list I'd like to show the following:

- Topic A - Y's msg
- Topic C - Y's msg
- Topic B - X's msg

My current sql merely grabs the sequence correctly, but get's the same topics as well:

- Topic A - Y's msg
- Topic A - Z's msg
- Topic C - Y's msg
- Topic B - X's msg
- Topic A - X's msg

  SELECT topic_subject, post_date, post_msg, post_by, cat_color
  FROM topics, posts, categories
  WHERE topic_id = post_topic
  AND topic_cat = cat_id
  ORDER BY post_date DESC

If I add GROUP BY topic_subject or its id, I get the original topic creators, such as the following:

- Topic C - Y's msg
- Topic B - X's msg
- Topic A - X's msg

Do I need a subquery for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `not exists` subquery :

```
select topic_subject, post_date, post_msg, post_by, cat_color 
from topics, posts p, categories 
where topic_id = post_topic AND topic_cat = cat_id
and not exists 
(
  select 1 
  from posts 
  where post_topic = p.post_topic and post_date > p.post_date
)
```